# imacros loop based csv values with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, imacros

i want to loop an action on iMacros based on some csv values. for example, record one is looping for 20 times and record two is looping for 10 times and these values saved on csv file. if i'm using javascript, the loop would be static and apply for all records. so, if anyone know how to doing that, i would be appreciate it.
this is my sample imacros code

```
var loop = "10"; // Loop
var build;
build =  "CODE:";
build +=  "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE source.csv" + "\n"; 
build +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 7" + "\n"; 
build +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; 
build +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n"; 
build +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
build +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
build +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=NAME:content CONTENT=" + "\n"; 
build +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=name:generate" + "\n";
for (i=0;i<loop;i++) {
iimPlay(build);
}
```

so, each loop made has different count. but, because i'm using javascript the loop would be use static count and apply for every record. i need to javascript read loop values on csv file and apply on script. but, as i know that javascript can't use {{!COL}} tags from imacros. sorry for my bad english and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this code bellow and work towards the code you want. To start you can't declare loop as a string and use it in i loop. It has to be numeric value. Secondly use iimSet to set the loop inside iMacros JavaScript macro. And in it instead of {{!LOOP}} you have to put {{loop}} . The example is bellow.

```
  var loop = 10; // Loop

var build;
build =  "CODE:";
build +=  "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE source.csv" + "\n"; 
build +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 7" + "\n"; 
build +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; 
build +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{loop}}" + "\n"; 
build +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
build +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
build +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=NAME:content CONTENT=" + "\n"; 
build +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=name:generate" + "\n";


for (i=0;i<loop;i++) {
iimSet("loop",i)
iimPlay(build);
}
```